# ChartJS, show tooltip only for the Charts in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js, bootstrap-modal

I have multiple `ChartJS` charts, some of them are in `Bootstrap` modals.
I have disabled `tooltips` globally with below code:

```
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.enabled = false;
```

However, I would like to show tooltips for the Charts which are in Modal.
Tried with below code, but no luck:

```
 $('#showChartModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.enabled = true;
});
```

How can I show `tooltips` if Modal is open and disable again once modal is closed?

Comment: After testing again, I noticed the tooltips are enabling on Modal show. However, I have to close the Modal and open again, then only the tooltips are showing.

Comment: I have tried `show.bs.modal` as well.

Comment: Please share the runnable code either using jsfiddle or SO's inbuilt snippet. That would be easy to debug.